# How to fix 'access violation reading location' error in my c++ pythagorean triple finder?

Tags: c++, pythagorean

I'm currently making a Pythagorean triple finder. I've been able to make it work but now I'm cleaning the results the program returns to avoid repetition. The program would find a Pythag triple like 3, 4, 5 but would then find the same triple again as  4, 3, 5. To fix this I've added some code that stores the Pythag triple in 3 arrays: `storeA`, `storeB`, and `storeC`. Then I have a function iterate through the previously-stored variables and compare each one to the current value. To access the arrays in the comparison function, I had to make the arrays global. When I start the program it works fine but when I enter a value like 10 it fails with the error "Access violation reading location 0x011F5000." If someone could enlighten me on my error I would be very grateful.

`repetitionCheck` is the function I use to compare values.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int squared(int input);
bool pythagCheck(int a, int b, int c);
bool repetitionCheck(int a, int b, int c);

int x;
int increment;
int storeA[1000];
int storeB[1000];
int storeC[1000];

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

    //input
    cout << "Specify Boundary: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "\n\n";

    //function
    for (a=0; a<=x; a++) 
    {
        if (pythagCheck(a, b, c) && repetitionCheck(a, b, c))
        {
            increment++;
            storeA[increment] = a;
            storeB[increment] = b;
            storeC[increment] = c;
        }

        for (b=0; b<=x; b++) 
        {
            if (pythagCheck(a, b, c) && repetitionCheck(a, b, c))
            {
                increment++;
                storeA[increment] = a;
                storeB[increment] = b;
                storeC[increment] = c;
            }

            for (c=0; c<=x; c++) 
            {
                if (pythagCheck(a, b, c) && repetitionCheck(a, b, c))
                {
                    increment++;
                    storeA[increment] = a;
                    storeB[increment] = b;
                    storeC[increment] = c;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

int squared(int input)
{
    return input * input;
}

bool pythagCheck(int a, int b, int c) 
{
    if (squared(a) + squared(b) == squared(c) && a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0)
    {
            cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << endl;
            return true;
    }
}

bool repetitionCheck(int a, int b, int c) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i >= increment; i++) 
    {
        if (storeA[i] == b) { return false; }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i >= increment; i++) 
    {
        if (storeC[i] == c) { return false; }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What value do you enter for `x`? You generate `(x+1)^3` elements - that's going to exceed 1000 pretty quickly. Note that `repetitionCheck` always returns `true` - none of its loops ever run.

Comment: This would be an excellent time to learn to use a debugger to step through the code to see where it isn't behaving as you expect. Also, [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is a good read.

Comment: One very simple way to avoid repetition is to sort the values before testing them, or to ensure any tests you generate are always ordered (i.e. no need to start second number at 0 when the first number is 1)

Comment: Look at your `for` loops in `repetitionCheck`.  How many times will they execute?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks for the help! I fixed the stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the function

```
bool repetitionCheck(int a, int b, int c) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i >= increment; i++) 
    {
        if (storeA[i] == b) { return false; }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i >= increment; i++) 
    {
        if (storeC[i] == c) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The global variable `increment` is not explicitely initialzed. All variables should always be initialized.

But because it is a globale variable, the compiler will set it to its default value, which is 0.

When you then invoke the `repetitionCheck(a, b, c)` function, the for loop will run nearly forever (unitl i flips over to negative), because i is always >= increment. And then you access array indices > 1000, your array size.

Then you get a seg fault.

Maybe you meant <=  Could be a simple typo.

But. Check your loops:  <= is most certainly wrong in many loops.